# What does "const void * const *" mean in C?

Tags: c, pointers, opengl, constants

I'm looking at a function glMultiDrawElements in OpenGL and it defines one of it's parameters as having this type: `const GLvoid * const *`. Obviously GLvoid is just void but my question is what does the 2nd `const` even mean? Can it be ignored and if so can someone shed some light on why it's done this way.

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glMultiDrawElements.xhtml

Comment: Related: Have you ever visited [www.cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const+void%2A+const%2A+arg) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Comment: @WhozCraig That site is cool but unfortunately it says only "syntax error" in this case.

Comment: @smack0007 you provided [a var name](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const+void%2A+const%2A+arg), right?

Comment: @WhozCraig Apparently I did not. Thanks.

Comment: @smack0007 You are an American living in German contacting a Russian. Are you the agent 007?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The internet is a strange place. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

In this construction

```
const GLvoid * const *.
```

the second qualifier `const` means that pointer `const GLvoid *` is a const pointer.  That is it is a constant pointer that points to a const object of type `GLvoid`.

This parameter declaration

```
const GLvoid * const * indices
```

means that using pointer `indices` you may not change the pointer (or pointers if this pointer points to the first element of an array of pointers) it points to.

Consider the following example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( const char **p )
{
    p[0] = "B";
}

int main( void )
{
    const char * a[1] = { "A" };
    f( a );

    puts( a[0] );
}
```

This function will be compiled successfully and you can change the value of a[0].

However if you rewrite the program the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( const char * const *p )
{
    p[0] = "B";
}

int main( void )
{
    const char * a[1] = { "A" };
    f( a );

    puts( a[0] );
}
```

The compiler issues an error like

```
prog.c:10:10: error: read-only variable is not assignable
    p[0] = "B";
    ~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```